# Euler method for SIR model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, matlab

I know how to solve SIR model with ode45, but I just wanted to try it out using Euler Method.
The SIR model is:

$\dot S=-\beta IS \\ \dot I = \beta IS - \gamma I \\ \dot R = \gamma I$
The code that I wrote is

```
function Euler
deltaT=1;
s=1;
i=1e-6;
r=1-(s+i);
beta=1.4247;
gamma=0.14286-1e-6;
maxTime=70;
t=[0];
for n=1:maxTime
    t(n+1)=t(n)+deltaT;
    s(n+1)=s(n)-beta*s(n)*i(n)*deltaT;
    i(n+1)=i(n)+(beta*s(n)*i(n)-gamma*i(n))*deltaT;
    r(n+1)=r(n)+gamma*i(n)*deltaT;
end
figure
plot(0:maxTime,s)
hold on 
plot(0:maxTime,i)
hold on 
plot(0:maxTime,r)
```

when I make the step size to be 1, I get the following figure which looks like the expected behaviour.

[image]
But when I make the step size small= 0.001, I get a very different figure.
[image]

Why does the behaviour change when I change the step sizes. What have I done wrong in the code?

Comment: It looks like you only step 70 steps. If your time step is 1 then you should have something like the interval from 0 to 70. However, in your code, if your time step decreases, you will not come that far. So there is some problem with your scaling. I guess, without having a detailed look, that you only get the very beginning of the solution when you decrease the step.

Comment: You can see at "time" 70 in the second simulation that there is a difference between S and I appearing.

Comment: @user36196 I think the more I make the time step smaller, the longer I have to run(increase maxTime) in order to see the correct behaviour.

Comment: Yep, as the code stands, you're calculating for 70 timesteps, which for your first plot is 70 and for the second is 0.07

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an error in the code - you are only (as @mickep suggested) doing 70 time steps in total through your simulation, whatever the timestep. To get the same simulation time as before you need to change the line

`for n=1:maxTime`

to

`for n=1:(maxTime/deltaT)`

and change the plot commands to `plot (0:deltaT:maxTime,...)`. This would not change your first plot (as `deltaT=1`) but the second would change.

Secondly, it makes sense generally, to preallocate your arrays `t=zeros(1,maxTime/deltaT);` (and similarly for `s`, `i` and `r`).

Thirdly (and this is very minor), as `r` is just the remaining population, you don't need to solve this differential equation - just plot `1-(s+i)` for your recovered fraction.